# When should I use "do" for intensifying a clause?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> After interviewing with GTE’s IT Department, I was brought back for an interview with three people from Human Resources, then offered a job as a programmer. Dreams really **did** come true! No more hacking for me—I wouldn’t need it. I’d be getting paid for doing what I loved, at the place I loved doing it.

*Note: text extracted from book **"Ghost in the Wires: My Adventures as the Wrold's Most Wanted Hacker"**.*

Look at the text above, I'd like when I'd use or not that **"did"**?

I've already read some things about that it's for **intensifying** but I couldn't fully understand when I'd really should it.

Comment: Change "did" to "do" and you're on the right track.

Comment: It wouldn't be wrong to say "My dreams really came true!", but it's more idiomatic to use _did come_ (or, as Benjamin suggests, _do come_ if you mean "It is possible for dreams to come true".

Comment: @KateBunting The text above's extract from one book which I'm reading. You explained me above but I couldn't fully understand when should use or not "do/did". Would explain me more detail about that use?

Comment: We can use _do_ to emphasise our surprise or pleasure that something has happened which might have been expected not to. "You _did_ come after all!"  "The experiment _did_ work." The author is expressing his pleasure that he actually got his dream job. You would not use _did_ when there is nothing remarkable about the incident being described.